# Eclipse Code Templates for class

Tags: java, eclipse, code-templates

In  Eclipse code templates for class files are not clear.
Where do I define ${filecomment} and other elements?

[image: Eclipse Code Templates]

Answer (score 2):

Those are the placeholders/pre-defined variables that assist during the auto-completion and other string-literals are placed as it is.

#### Example

When you type `for` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, you placed the structured for loop with a local variable `i` defined and cursor placed at this position.

Go through this [ibm developer works tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/index.html) which explains this in great detail.